# Calculate the transpose of a list python without using numpy

Tags: python

How to calculate the transpose of this without using numpy:

```
t = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
t = list(zip(*t))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: Surely the list comprehension is unnecessary? Wouldn't `list(zip(*t))` be enough?